# Why does random.random() take up two random.randint() values?

Tags: python, random

I've developed a simple application that generates test data series and I've built it to be able to be repeatable, using a random seed. I noticed the following and wanted to know why this happens:

```
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(0,10)]
[2, 9, 1, 4, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 6]
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.random()
0.13436424411240122
>>> [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(0,10)]
[1, 4, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 6, 3, 1]
```

Note how a single call to random() uses up two values for randint(). I'm guessing this has something to do with the amount of random information required to generate a float vs. an int in the given range, but is there some way of keeping track of 'how many random values have been used so far?', i.e. how far along in the sequence of semi-random values the system is?

I ended up writing my own function, always using a single call to random.random() in its logic. So I'm not asking for a solution, just some background / an explanation.

Comment: You need 53 bits for a random double. For efficiency or simplicity, the RNG probably reads 32 bits at a time in both cases. Why do you need to keep track of the number of random values used? If it’s to synchronize some generators, there may be a better way.

Comment: @Ryan yeah, while this is an interesting question, I would be wary of relying on this sort of thing

Comment: Did you try with different seeds? That number (two) is not fixed. It is sometimes 1 (seed=6), sometimes 0 (seed=2). I am guessing the while loop [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L223) has something to do with it.

Comment: I have to say, this not appears in python3.5 + numpy 1.13.1 , so kindly add python and numpy version to your question.

Comment: Oh, with python2.7 + numpy 1.13.1 , I can't reproduce this problem too.

Comment: @StevenDu This is not related to numpy. Use `import random`.

Comment: OK,  my windows 10+python2.7 can't reproduce this problem regardless where the random is imported. But my ubuntu16.04 + python3.5 have same  problem.

Comment: @Grismar What version of Python are you using?

Comment: `random` is implemented in C. The [Source Code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_randommodule.c#L141) tells us that one call to `random` requires two calls to `genrand_int32` so your first assumption is correct. I don't think there is a way to access internal state of generator, However you can use [`getstate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getstate) and [`setstate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.setstate) to manage your random sequences.

Comment: I don't think this question is straightforward to answer. @bro-grammer while there are two underlying C calls to `genrand_int32()` from a `random.random()`, there seems to be a possibility of multiple calls from `random.randint()` depending on the size of the random number (see [random_getrandbits](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6708be744d032aeffab3e2cf0b064a41a719d8a1/Modules/_randommodule.c#L390)). The size will depend on the start and stop given to `random.randint()`.

Comment: Also, between Python 2.7.10 and 3.5.2 on my machine, I see a difference in output of the same code above. This is possibly due to changes in PyObject types and in the random code itself between versions, but I suspect there could be compiler/machine dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is accurate, at least for the latest version of CPython. There are a couple of relevant places in the code for the random module where you can see why this is happening. I would consider all of this an implementation detail, but you can see that essentially, groups of 32 random bits are generated as needed to get random numbers. For this reason, getting 53 random bits (to represent the fractional part of a double) uses twice as many random bits as getting 4 random bits.

- [random.randint Python code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L217)
- [random._randbelow Python code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L223)
- [random.getrandbits C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_randommodule.c#L390)
- [random.random C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_randommodule.c#L141)

With respect to being able to tell how much random data has been generated, the provided functions don't seem to give you an easy and reliable way of doing that.

Comment: It's a bit subtler than this, since `_randbelow` does a form of [rejection sampling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/310b424c476e3de3370990e5b9a10acc64ed17f8/Lib/random.py#L234-L235): 68.75% of calls to `randint(0, 10)` will need only one call to `getrandbits`, but the other 31.25% of calls will need two or more calls. (The expected number of calls to `_randbelow` will be 16/11.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson true, but I wasn’t sure if that was information the question was looking for. I tried to stick to the “twice as many values” part of it and provide the relevant links in the code. Definitely edit if you feel that the rejection sampling is part of what OP was asking for.

Comment: I appreciate the added detail @MarkDickinson, but I think the concise answer is good without the added complication.